# Will refreshing via meta tag cause any performance issues?

Tags: javascript, meta-tags, page-refresh, alfresco-share

I am new to web application and I dont know java script ( I am learning now). I am experimenting with [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/). It is an open source Enterprise Management System. It has a discussion page where user post any question and other user responds. Unluckily Alfresco does not provide auto refresh of the page. So manually the user has to refresh the page inorder to find whether anybody responded to his question. So I planned to add the function. It was said in a blog that auto refreshing via java script is not good idea because it wont work if user disabled java script.

In alfresco there is no `.html` files. There is `.html.ftl`. After using firebug I found the file corresponding to the page and I added the meta tag to refresh the page automatically.

Here is the meta tag
`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="100">`

Will refreshing via meta tag cause any performance issues if there is 150-200 users logged in at the same time?

Is there any efficient way to do the same?

Thanks

Comment: Performance issues for what, the server, client, or network? Btw: Where is the timeout?

Comment: I edited. I am asking for client and server.